# Silverlight Capture to mp4 C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, mp4

I'm currently working on a silverlight application for a client. 
is there any way to capture the application to a mp4 file format using C# on the client side?? For use to review the user actions?

Comment: You wouldn't be better off just auditing the user actions (like mouse-clicks etc) and retrieving those for analysis?

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short, there is defenetly no way doing this at client side!

Comment: Times change and so does answers:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/10/silverlight-4-more-on-capturing-video-from-webcams.aspx